# Take value from user for linked list till user press 0 and then display output in c++

Tags: c++

In this program I want to take value from user in linked list till the user enters *0* and display output of that Linked List. I think problem there came is that value is over-writing the same node. I am taking input in function **void create_node()**. Please guide in order to find error!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int ID;

    node *next;         
};

class line
{
private:
    node *head, *tail;          
public:
    line ()
    {
        head = tail = NULL;         
    }

    void create_node()
    {
        node *my_node = new node;
        int a;

        for(;;)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a value to Liked List:";
            cin>>a;
            my_node-> ID = a;
            my_node-> next = NULL;

            if(my_node-> ID!=0)
            {
                if(!head)
                {
                    head = tail = my_node;
                }
                else
                {
                    tail-> next = my_node;
                    tail = tail-> next;
                }
            }
            else if(my_node-> ID==0)
            {
                cout<<"0 come"<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // create_node end here

    void display()          
    {
        node *t = head;                 
        if(!head)               
        {
            cout<<"Linked list not exists!!!"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (t!=NULL)
            {
                cout<<"ID: "<<t->ID<<endl;

                cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;

                t = t-> next;   
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    void Search(int number)
    {
        node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            if(number == tmp->ID)
            {
                cout << "number " <<tmp->ID << " is found!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    */
};

int main ()
{
    line obj;
    obj.create_node();

    obj.display();

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Names are important. Your function is named `create_node()`. Without looking inside, how many nodes should it create?

Comment: about naming I encourage you to name your types with an uppercase for the first letter to easily distinguish variables and types, so *Node* and *Line*

Comment: What is the actual problem you have? You didn't describe anything! Please read [ask]. Also, as a new user, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

`node *my_node = new node;`

This should be inside the for loop if you want to keep creating new nodes. The check to see if user has entered 0 should be done before creating the new node, if you don't want a new node to be created for 0.

```
    int a;

for(;;)
{
    cout<<"Enter a value to Liked List:";
    cin>>a;
    node *my_node = new node;
```

...

If new node is not created, then it will keep overwriting for the same node and it will have `0`.

As pointed in the comments, name the function better to reflect what's being done inside.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a new node for each value that the user enters. You are creating only 1 node and indeed overwriting it each time.

You should move the user input out of `create_node()` altogether. It doesn't belong there. Handle the user input in `main()` instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int ID;
    node *next;
};

class linkedList
{
private:
    node *head, *tail;

public:
    linkedList()
    {
        head = tail = NULL;
    }

    ~linkedList()
    {
        node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp) {
            node *next = tmp->next;
            delete tmp;
            tmp = next;
        }
    }

    void create_node(int number)
    {
        node *my_node = new node;
        my_node->ID = number;
        my_node->next = NULL;

        if (!head) head = my_node;
        if (tail) tail->next = my_node;
        tail = my_node;
    }

    void display()
    {
        if (!head)
        {
            cout << "Linked list is empty!!!"<< endl;
        }
        else
        {
            node *tmp = head;
            do
            {
                cout << "ID: "<< tmp->ID << endl;
                cout << "------------------------" << endl;
                tmp = tmp-> next;
            }
            while (tmp);
        }
    }

    /*
    void Search(int number)
    {
        node *tmp = head;
        while (tmp)
        {
            if (number == tmp->ID)
            {
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if (tmp) {
            cout << "number " << number << " is found!" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "number " << number << " is not found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    */
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList obj;
    int a;

    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value to add to Linked List: ";
        cin >> a;

        if (a != 0)
        {
                obj.create_node(a);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "0 come" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    obj.display();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```